# How is Deutsche Bank's vermögung service ROBIN?

Tags: etf, bank-account, germany

I have been searching for different possibilities to invest in the markets for long term holding and trading. I do not intend to do leverage based trading and working with leveraged ETF's is not in my mind at the moment. I came across Deutsche Bank's service ROBIN where they are offering individual service for individual customer to build the portfolio based on the % of ris. At the moment I am thinking about opting to 15% risk varient.

In the website they have mentioned 0.75% vegütung p.a and 0.25% ETF-kosten. They say there are not any more hidden costs. Do i need to look for any cost in specific ? and Also i donot understand 0.25% ETF cost, are they talking about the expense ratio or is this ETF-kosten saperate from expense ratio ? If anyone have experience with ROBIN service from Deutsche bank please help me clarify this.

Comment: 1% cost is huge. You can do a bit of research and get the same for free.

Comment: That is what I am confused , if that 0.75% vergütung includes everything and no more of specific hidden and holding costs, i guess it is on par with other services like etoro to open trading account ( considering initial stages with less capital i.e. less than 50k ) as services like erotor has specific holding and hidden costs along with cash withdrawal costs. Hence I am wondering whether there is anyone who have experience with this service and can clear me out.